# Why does an error pop up when installing the "librosa" library in the PyCharm development environment: "subprocess-exited-with-error"?

Tags: python, installation, pycharm, librosa

Here is the error itself. To install, I use the command "pip install librosa", Python version 3.11.0

```
Collecting numba\>=0.45.1
Using cached numba-0.56.4.tar.gz (2.4 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[8 lines of output\]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\<string\>", line 2, in \<module\>
File "\<pip-setuptools-caller\>", line 34, in \<module\>
File "C:\\Users\\merge\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qgu9dc69\\numba_22de5875b2534efba1d1a87fc556500b\\setup.py", line 51, in \<module\>
\_guard_py_ver()
File "C:\\Users\\merge\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qgu9dc69\\numba_22de5875b2534efba1d1a87fc556500b\\setup.py", line 48, in \_guard_py_ver
raise RuntimeError(msg.format(cur_py, min_py, max_py))
RuntimeError: Cannot install on Python version 3.11.0; only versions \>=3.7,\<3.11 are supported.
\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─\> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried to install not in Pycharm and changed the version of Python, I did not find anything on the Internet about this error, everywhere they suggest installing via "conda". Is there another way?

Comment: `Numba` is not available on Python 3.11.0. Use lower version.